# What's a good practice to separate client and server code in Node in an isomorphic React driven application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build an isomorphic application on Node with React being rendered initially to client from the server, and have it bundled via Webpack for client side rendering and UI purposes.

However, I'm having issues with separating client side with server side. The React components that are bundled (and work fine) on Client also get run on the server side. Therefore, trying to change states or loading data is not possible because the component is run on both server and client.

How do I effectively separate these? Or do I have to make a separate component folder for client and server (for server, leave out data handling).

Not sure how this is properly done in Node for a smooth running Isomorphic application.

Comment: أنا بصدد إعداد 
`express-react-mvc` .. will be delivered soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could learn a lot from the boilerplate [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) and from the starter kit [react-universally](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally). Both are designed to provide universal rendering.

From experience, based on [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) that we used in our company, we have:

- to [load dynamic data server-side](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L92) when generating your page (for example to fill a flux store)
- [generate html](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L104) body with React
- send both [the data](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/helpers/Html.js#L52) and the [ReactJS html body](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/helpers/Html.js#L51) client-side. The produces html will be displayed at screen ( make sure to have css loaded first to avoid FOC effect)
- regenerate client-side your application state to have the data available for react component.
- run the javascript that launch the React single app client side: The react component should not make any request to load data because you have already generate client-side the application state.

Hope that help you :)